# From submit in a AJAX-generated tabs (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to submit a from which is located into a tabs. This tabs content is generated via AJAX.

My problem is that when I submit the form, the page refresh and the "default" tab is loaded so the php function generating the tab with the form never receive the post data.

Here the solutions I though about :

1) The easiest : Finding a way to insert a hash in the URL so that when the page refresh, a javascript code load the good tab.

2) The best (considering user experience) : Finding a way to submit the form with ajax and add the new entry to the list under the form in the tab. BUT I want to use php to check form values (is_empty(), etc.). I thought about sending data to the php controller, then, hide the form and replace it with the new form generated by the php controller (with error messages or empty fields if fields were ok and data added to the DB).

Here is my code :

The layout :

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#profile" data-url="/Shawili/<?= $profile['username'] ?>/profile/">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" data-url="/Shawili/<?= $profile['username'] ?>/about/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#wishlist" data-url="/Shawili/<?= $profile['username'] ?>/wishlists/">Wishlists <span class="badge"><?= $profile['wishlists'] ?></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#following" data-url="">Following <span class="badge"><?= $profile['following'] ?></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#followers" data-url="">Followers <span class="badge"><?= $profile['followers'] ?></span></a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="about">about</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="wishlist">wl</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="following">following</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="followers">followers</div>
</div>
```

The tab :

```
<?php

if($owner)
{   ?>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
    <fieldset><legend>Add a wishlist</legend>
        <?php echo $form; ?>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="addwishlist">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<hr />

<?php
}

?>

<div class="row">
<?php

foreach($wishlists as $wishlist)
{ //Here we display whislists } ?>
```

The php controller that corresponding to the tabs view :

```
$manager = $this->managers->getManagerOf('Wishlist');

    /**
    *  Adding a new wishlist
    */

    if($owner)
    {

        //Creating object. Depends on form validation
        if ($request->postExists('addwishlist'))
        {
            $wishlist = new \Lib\Entities\Wishlist(array(
            'title' => $request->postData('title'),
            'comment' => $request->postData('comment'),
            'user' => $this->app->user()->getUser(),    
          ));
        }
        else
        {
            $wishlist = new \Lib\Entities\Wishlist;
        }

        //generating form 
        $formBuilder = new \Lib\Forms\WishlistForm($wishlist);
        $formBuilder->build();
        $form = $formBuilder->form();
            $formHandler = new \Lib\FormHandler($form, $manager, $request);

            //if form has been validate : add the wishlist and set flash
            if ($formHandler->process('add'))
            {
            $this->app->user()->setFlash('Your wish list has been created !');
        $this->app->httpResponse()->redirect('/Shawili/'.$request->getData('user').'/wishlists/');
            }

            $this->page->addVar('form', $form->createView());

    }

    /**
    *  Displaying user's wishlists
    */


    $wishlists = $manager->getWishlists($request->getData('user'), $this->app->user()->getUser());


    $this->page->addVar('wishlists', $wishlists);
    $this->page->addVar('owner', $owner);
    $this->page->addVar('profile', $request->getData('user'));
    $this->page->addVar('cuser', $this->managers->getManagerOf('User')->getUser($this->app->user()->getUser()));
```

The Jquery code :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    var href = this.hash;
    var pane = $(this);

    // ajax load from data-url
    $(href).load(url,function(result){      
        pane.tab('show');
    });
});

// load first tab content
$('#profile').load($('.active a').attr("data-url"),function(result){
  $('.active a').tab('show');
});

    </script>
```

Any suggestion of the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Second option is rather widely used practice and it always works well, so you can use it without concern. 
Looking at your code I suppose, that you want to generate form code and send it via ajax to browser. It is not necessarily best way to do it. You don't have to hide and replace form. You can easyly modify existing one with jQuery.
The trick is to send to the browser only formated data containing info about errors etc. (for example using [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)) and then decode it ([jQuery way](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)) and localy modify content of web page.

To submit form via ajax you can just overwrite click event for the button and then collect data from fields and send it to the server, for example like this:

```
$("#submit_button_id").click(function(){
    var formdata = $("#form_id").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/submit_url",
        data: formdata,
        success: function(RESPONSE){
            //Your code to modify page content after geting RESPONSE.
        }
    })
    return false; //To prevent page from reloading
}
```